# PhpStorm - Prevent disabling "Create new project from existing files" option

Tags: phpstorm

I had tried to solve this issue many times, but the only helpful solution was to reinstall and remove all old settings.

What wrong happen because this is a common issue with PhpStorm for many years.

How to prevent or how to solve this issue without the reinstall?

[image]

Comment: What exactly is "this issue"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please ensure that you have **"Remote Hosts Access" plugin** enabled -- as simple as that.

P.S. I have no ideas why it may become automatically disabled in some cases. Maybe `idea.log` file can shed some light on that (`Help | Show Log in XX`).